# In Ansible, is there a way to use a variable name as a value?

Tags: loops, variables, ansible

I have a hash that I'm looping over in Ansible.

```
site1:
    some_config: value1
    some_other_config: value2
site2:
    some_config: value3
    some_other_config: value4
```

Using the hash, I'm trying to create some files using templates, like so:

```
- name: create config files
  template: src=templates/site.conf.j2 dest=/etc/nginx/conf.d/site-{{item???}}.conf
  with_items:
      - "{{site1}}"
      - "{{site2}}"
```

I'm able to refer to the variables `item.some_config` and others from inside the template. But I want to **name the destination files with the names of the variables**. Like so,

`site-site1.conf` and `site-site2.conf`

How can I refer to the variable names as values?

(Easy workaround would be to add another key in each variable with values as `site1` and `site2`. But that would just be redundant)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `with_dict` instead of `with_items` in this case with slight modification, here is a full working example:

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
   sites:
     site1:
       some_config: value1
       some_other_config: value2
     site2:
       some_config: value3
       some_other_config: value4
  tasks:
    - name: create config files
      template:
        src: site.conf.j2 
        dest: "/etc/nginx/conf.d/site-{{ item.key }}.conf"
      with_dict: "{{ sites }}"
```

Inside your template, you can refer the value like this:

```
{{ item.value.some_config }}
{{ item.value.some_other_config }}
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be on the right track with your final paragraph but I think you're missing the simpler data structure here.

Instead your configuration could be set up like this:

```
configuration:
 - destination: site1
   some_config: value1
   some_other_config: value2
 - destination: site2
   some_config: value3
   some_other_config: value4
```

And you can then refer to it like this:

```
- name: create config files
  template: src=templates/site.conf.j2 dest=/etc/nginx/conf.d/site-{{item.destination}}.conf
  with_items: configuration
```

Now, when you need to add more templates to your task you only need to change the `configuration` variable block and not the actual task. If this ends up being overridden at an environment level (via group vars or such) then this becomes a lot more flexible.

Comment: I ended up modifying the data structure as you suggested. It's a more elegant solution as compared to what I was trying to do.